# The marker is not rendering in the mapbox-gl

Tags: reactjs, coordinates, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, web-frontend

I have just started to use the mapbox-gl but i am unable to get a marker or a pin to a location it is not rendering a pin but the map is rendered i want to render a pointer on the map and i want to get the co-ordinates of that position i am not getting any idea of doing so, it will be of great help if u help me

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactMapboxGl, { Layer, Feature, Marker, Popup } from "react-mapbox-gl";
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";
import { Img } from "@chakra-ui/react";
const TOKEN = process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN;
function Map() {
  const [newPlace, setNewPlace] = useState(null);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(0);
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(0);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(13);
  const Map = ReactMapboxGl({
    accessToken:
      "xyz",
  });
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
      <Map
        style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
        containerStyle={{
          height: "70vh",
          width: "70vw",
        }}
        center={[lng, lat]}
        zoom={[zoom]}
      >
        <Marker longitude={lng} latitude={lat} anchor="bottom">
          <img src="./pin.jpg" />
        </Marker>
      </Map>
      ;
    </div>
  );
}
export default Map;
```

Comment: I am getting a similar issue with React + Mapbox. Did you find a solution?